# can memory for a golang variable be used outside its declaration scope

Tags: go, memory-management

I am trying to understand memory management in go. can i safely use the memory allocated inside a scope.

```
type BigConfigurationData struct {
   subject1config *Subject1Config
   subject2config *Subject2Config
   ...
}

var p BigConfigurationData
if aFlag {
   var subject1config = Subject1Config {
      foo: bar
   }
   p.subject1config = &subject1config
}
// can i use p.subject1config here and expect the memory has not been cleaned up?
```

Comment: The garbage collector collects *garbage* - values to which there are *no references*. If you can try to use it, you must have a reference to it, therefor it isn't garbage, and won't be collected.

Comment: Also read https://golang.org/doc/faq#stack_or_heap

Comment: You're not referencing anything outside of it's declaration scope, as `subject1config` is part of `p`, which is of course declared in the same scope you're using it.

Answer (score -1):

Go looks simple, but in fact it does a lot to help the programmer.

In Go all variables are effectively references. The compiler tracks if any memory "escapes" a scope, and then automatically allocates is on the heap (shared memory pool). If the memory does not escape the scope, compiler allocates it on the stack which is much faster.

In your case, when you assign the p.subject1config = &subject1config, this tells the compiler that the value or the memory will leave the scope. Compiler will allocte the memory from heap and thus via the reference p.subject1config you can access the memory in the outer scope.

Go garbage collector regularly checks if the memory blocks still have any refences pointing to it, and frees up the memory when no references remain.

In short, you are confusing "variable" and "memory", probably because Go automatically manages memory for you.

EDIT: This answer might be too simplisic. Please read comments below for more info. See these links for more information:
http://www.tapirgames.com/blog/golang-memory-management
https://dougrichardson.org/2016/01/23/go-memory-allocations.html

Comment: Oh, please, don't add to the confusion! The statement «In Go all variables are effectively references» is plain wrong. The fact you can return *a pointer to* a variable of any type from a function, and the escape analysis done by compiler will notice this fact and will make sure the *pointed to* variable is allocated on the heap to be able to outlive the scope of the function in which it was created, still has nothing to do with its semantics —simply because a pointer is explicitly used, and *it* is what has reference semantics, not the variable it points to.

Comment: Thanks @kostix. I really tried not to add to confusion.  From my understanding it is not as simple as "do we have a reference" but there is real, albeit simple escape analysis. So even if you use pointers but don't return them compiler will use stack. I do agree that in sample code provided there is no return. But I do think my explanation is relevant. If you recommend how to better explain it, I am open to changing my answer... One of my references: www.agardner.me/golang/garbage/collection/gc/escape/analysis/2015/10/18/go-escape-analysis.html

Comment: The essense of your answer is quite okay, IMO, but wording is paramount: any newfangled gopher who would read «In Go all variables are effectively references» would beleive this is true and would spread this nonsense forward—no matter whether the surrounding context of that phrase downplayed its boldness and falsehood or not.

Comment: The reason for be being so picky about this is that the distinction about reference/value semantics in Go is already a pain point for certain kind of freshmen—those coming from languages such as JS or Python or PHP where values of any type other than primitive (such as `int`) is passed by reference; these people usually have troubles grasping the idea that in Go everything (and I mean this literally) is passed by value *but* at the same there are types which implement reference semantics—both built-in and created by the user.

Comment: Hence there's no need to add to the confusion—especially such needlessly and factually false but bold claims. Here's a simple example: <https://play.golang.org/p/uZDb1f3rE26>. As you can see, the variable created in the function "is returned" from it, but this means its *value* is returned *by copying* it, not returning a reference to it somehow.

Comment: Agreed @kostix. I don't think I can sufficiently edit the answer to point out the difference. I will however add reference to this exchange.